# Storing subclasses with same properties in a data store

Tags: java, inheritance, datastore

What’s the best way to store inheritance in a database like Neo4j?

Let’s say I have two types of vehicle; car and test car, where test car inherits from car. In our example there’s no difference in properties so all data stored in the data store is the same, but in our app's model, test car has methods that car doesn’t.

Is it best to store a new property like `car_type` with some kind of enum? Or is there a better way to store/determine a subclass when downloading and initting it in an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using labels.  So if you had vehicles, of which you had cars and buses, you might have the labels `Vehicle`, `Car`, and `Bus` and all nodes with the labels `Car` and `Bus` would also have the label `Vehicle`.

If you want to see an example, the neo4j gem for ruby does this to represent class inheritance for models which users of the gem define.

Comment: I can’t believe I didn’t think of labels. For some reason I didn’t connect the two in my head despite already using labels as the highest form of the class. e.g. all subclasses of Car have labels ‘Car’.